# I am not as you wish to be. Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

**I am not as what you expect ?** Is this one also a valid? Are there any grammatical errors? **I'm not as you wish to be?** Please correct me if there is something wrong in the above sentences.

Comment: I am not as you wish me to be.

Comment: @Lambie How different is it from **"I'm not what..."**?

Comment: I am not as you wish me to me [grammatical and formal]. I'm not what you want me to be. =less formal but also can mean something different: I'm not what you want me to be [like you want me to be, and not doing the profession you want me to be doing].

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to say, **"I'm not as you wish me to be."** The absence of "me" changes the direct object from "you" to "me." In other words, the way you are phrasing it suggests that "you" wish to be like me, as opposed to you wishing me to be someone different.

**"I am not what you expect."** or **"I am not as you expect."** are correct (though a "me to be" is implied on the end of them and making it explicit would be good), but "I am not as what you expect." is not correct. "As" and "what" are both verbs, and can't be used together in this way.